# Comic where a robot "takes apart" a man's body while he's alive

Tags: story-identification, comics, horror, robots

I remember seeing a comic book in the early 90's (was it based on a movie like *Creepshow* or *Tales From the Crypt*?) where a man (possibly a scientist) finds a cute little robot and, out of curiosity, takes him apart to see what makes him tick. Then a larger robot (an alien robot?) appears and is mortified that his sentient little friend (child?) has been brutalized like this.

Later, another man approaches and the original man can be heard inside a building of some sort (a shed?) talking but under stress, and when the new character enters, he finds to his utter horror that the curious man from before has had his entire body disassembled, with veins and tissue stretched out all along the area, his body still fully functional, but completely opened up and laid out for all internal parts to be visible, like an exploded schematic.

Answer (score 6):

Good lord...! (choke!) This story is 'Disassembled!' from EC's *Weird Science* #18, 1953. Story by Bill Gaines & Al Feldstein, art by Joe Orlando. Huston (hope you are still on-site) you remember the story almost exactly, except the dissected robot wasn't a child. This story has been reprinted many times, so it is probably the one you are thinking of - although EC had a habit of lifting stories from other sources...

[image]

Comment: [This page on comics.org](https://www.comics.org/issue/10430/) lists 5 reprints.

Comment: Broderick's expression is so very "_Some_ people knock before entering."

Comment: Some people have no manners.